# My Dialog on Android comes up Blank

Tags: android

So I'm trying to create a dialog pop up. Here's the Dialog fragment I created in a separate DialogClass.Java file

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DialogClass extends DialogFragment{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    AlertDialog.Builder newAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    newAlertDialog.setTitle("Dialog");
    newAlertDialog.setMessage("This is a dialog");
    newAlertDialog.setPositiveButton(("OK"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ("You clicked Ok"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    newAlertDialog.setNegativeButton(("Cancel"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ("You clicked Cancel"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

  }
}
```

Then when I use this class to create a method it brings us a blank dialog box when I run the app. This is how I use it:
Note: myButtinClick is a method that runs on the click of a button.

```
 public void myButtonClick(View view) {

    DialogFragment myFrag = new DialogClass();
    myFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
}
```

Please can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

See a screenshot of what the Dialog looks like via this link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsQQj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only created the Dialog builder, but not the Dialog itself.
You should return `newAlertDialog.create()` and rename `newAlertDialog` to `dialogBuilder` or something like that.